# What does this performance formula mean?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, evolutionary-computing

I have to make a quick clustering program but the following formula is gibberish to me:

> $\operatorname{Perf}(X,C) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\min\{||X_i-C_l||^2  \mid  l = 1,...,K\}$
>
> where $X$ is a set of multi-dimensional data and $C$ is a set of centroids for each data cluster.

This formula is a fitness function for an [artificial bee colony clustering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_bee_colony_algorithm) as a substitute for [k-means clustering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering_algorithm). It is described as a total
within-cluster variance or the total mean-square quantization error (MSE).

Can anyone translate it to *pseudo-code*, normal human *English*, or at least enlighten me?

Comment: I don't think pseudocode or "human" English would be particularly enlightening. I suggest you learn how to read such formula; that opens up whole troughs of knowledge for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just break it down into parts:

> $  \{ f(l) \mid l = 1,...,K \} $

This is a simple set construction. The above would simply create a set with all the elements from 1 to K. In your case the `f(l)` is the function:

> $ ||X_i-C_l||^2 $

Given the `||` means the norm, these are vectors you are subtracting (rows of the X and C matrices). So subtract the vectors, take the norm, and square it. That produces a new set, of which you want to take the minimum.

> $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n $

This part is then just the sum of above min calculation for every index $i$ from $1$ to $n$.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove all short-hands resp. unfold the notation, you get

$\qquad \begin{align}
\operatorname{Perf}(X,C) = \quad  &\min \{ ||X_1−C_1||^2, ||X_1−C_2||^2, \dots, ||X_1−C_K||^2 \} \\
+ &\min \{ ||X_2−C_1||^2, ||X_2−C_2||^2, \dots, ||X_2−C_K||^2 \} \\
  &\ \ \vdots \\
+ &\min \{ ||X_n−C_1||^2, ||X_n−C_2||^2, \dots, ||X_n−C_K||^2 \} \\
\end{align}$

where

- $\min$ denotes the minimum value of the operand set,
- $X_i$ and $C_l$ are rows or columns of the matrices (depends on the source),
- $u - v$ for vectors $u,v$ is component-wise subtraction and
- $||u||$ for a vector $u$ is a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) (which one depends on your source; if nothing else is stated, usually the [Euclidian norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) is meant).

So, $\operatorname{Perf}(X,C)$ finds for every row (column) of $X$ the row (column) of $C$ that is nearest, and sums up all those minimum (squared) distances. It is therefore a measure of *closeness*: if $\operatorname{Perf}(X,C)=0$ then every row (column) in $X$ has a perfect match in $C$ (because norms are non-negative).